# How to make a removable media (USB stick) recognized by Debian11 netinst?

Tags: debian-installer, firmware

I'm trying to install Debian 11 `firmware-11.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso` from:
[11.3.0+nonfree](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/11.3.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-cd/) an the A6-5400K machine (see below).

Of many attempts the most successful end up with:

```
[!!] Detect network hardware
A driver for your hardware is not available.
...
Load missing drivers from removable media?
```

and after inserting the USB stick (see below what it has)

```
[!!] Detect network hardware
No kernel modules were found [skip]
```

The target machine is AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon Version E7792AMS V2.2. The machine was running Windows7. From "research" I did before installing Debian11 I know that I need `rtl8168e-3.fw` (the `.iso` image above doesn't have it).

The package [firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb) has the file.

The USB stick's content which I use as a removable media (with the drivers):

```
/:
firmware  firmware-realtek  firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb

/firmware:
firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb

/firmware-realtek:
firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb
```

all ends up as I described. The similar problem was reported many times (usually for earlier releases). However I found neither solution nor workaround I could follow up. I use two USB sticks; one has bootable `.iso` file, the other the `.deb` file as described.

**EDIT**

With the hindsight the workaround looks quite simple. From firmware-11.3.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso I installed everything that doesn't require the network support. After rebooting into the new system I installed

```
# dpkg -i firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb
# dpkg -i firmware-atheros_20210315-3_all.deb
```

(had to add /sbin to PATH). After rebooting made /etc/apt/sources.list. After that I was able to install the packages I need that require the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with netinst, but you can do it with a live system, that you make persistent live. The smallest debian live iso files are named 'standard', for example [debian-live-11.3.0-amd64-standard.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-11.3.0-amd64-standard.iso). The tool [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian) can make a persistent live USB drive from it.

Comment: The idea is to "$ dpkg -i firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb" when the Debian11 is running, isn't it? I guess I could go without mkusb in that case, as soon as I installed the OS,the chages was permament.

Comment: I was only suggesting a workaround. I have not enough experience with the netinst installing method. You know more than I about that, and someone who knows much more than I should help you. Let us hope that you will find that person :-)

Comment: it is a "research" work ) "I: update-initramfs is disabled (live system is running on read-only media). seems I can't use dpkg -i

Comment: If you try with a persistent live system, I should be able to help you: After creating the system and booting into it, if you wish, you can install program packages and tweaks and add own shellscripts etc to make it do a lot of things more or less automatically.